# Efficiently Finding DOM Elements Appearing over a Specified DOM Element

Tags: javascript, css, dom, position

How can I efficiently find all of the DOM elements that are on top of a specified query element?

That is, I want a Javascript function that when I pass in a reference to a DOM element will return an array of all DOM elements that have non-zero overlap with the input element and appear above it visually. My specific goal is to find those elements that may be visually blocking elements below them.

The context is one in which I do not have advanced knowledge of the web page, the query element, or much of anything else. Elements can appear above others for a variety of reasons.

I can of course do this through an exhaustive search of the DOM, but that's very inefficient and not practical when the DOM tree grows large. I could also use the newer elementFromPoint to sample positions from within the query element to ensure that it is indeed on top, but that seems pretty inefficient.

Any ideas on how to do this better?

Thanks!

Comment: html, and by extension the DOM, are about hierarchical structure of data. CSS is what puts them into place. Therefore, you can't make a lot of visual assumptions about a given element. So pretty much no matter what, the solution won't be pretty and/or very efficient.

Comment: agreed, but often there are tricks or browser-specific methods for doing inefficient things … for instance, elementfrompoint is javascript access to something otherwise very inefficient to compute

Comment: `elementFromPoint` is actually your best bet, and will likely be the most reliable solution. While I wouldn't recommend calling `elementFromPoint` for every pixel in the specified element, you could come up with an algorithm to make it more efficient. For example, you can start by checking the four points of the bounding rectangle.

Comment: That said, if you let us know WHY you think you need to be able to do this (i.e. what problem are you trying to solve?), we might be able to inform you on a better method of achieving your desired result.

Comment: I'm trying to automatically test for specific kinds of layout breaks - one of the worst is when elements containing useful content overlap one another.  So, for instance, if you shrink the browser viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a simpler way than using elementFromPoint. You don't seem to want to use it but can give you some consistent result.
If there are multi layered elements, you should adapt your code to move already grabbed elements or set them invisible and recall function to get new set of data elements.

For the basic idea:

```
function upperElements(el) {
    var top = el.offsetTop,
        left = el.offsetLeft,
        width = el.offsetWidth,
        height = el.offsetHeight,
        elemTL = document.elementFromPoint(left, top),
        elemTR = document.elementFromPoint(left + width - 1, top),
        elemBL = document.elementFromPoint(left, top + height - 1),
        elemBR = document.elementFromPoint(left + width - 1, top + height - 1),
        elemCENTER = document.elementFromPoint(parseInt(left + (width / 2)), parseInt(top + (height / 2))),
        elemsUpper = [];
    if (elemTL != el) elemsUpper.push(elemTL);
    if (elemTR != el && $.inArray(elemTR, elemsUpper) === -1) elemsUpper.push(elemTR);
    if (elemBL != el && $.inArray(elemBL, elemsUpper) === -1) elemsUpper.push(elemBL);
    if (elemBR != el && $.inArray(elemBR, elemsUpper) === -1) elemsUpper.push(elemBR);
    if (elemCENTER != el && $.inArray(elemCENTER, elemsUpper) === -1) elemsUpper.push(elemCENTER);
    return elemsUpper;
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLbZH/)

Comment: +1. [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) is definitely the way to go, as it has access to the browser's render stack

Comment: to add additional complexity you also need to consider `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate but **there is no way to have a solution that will not iterate through all DOM element**, because you can put any element anywhere on screen through CSS rules.

The best you can do it actually iterating over all the DOM elements to make a hit test.

If I had to do this, I would rely on jQuery, which is a widely used cross-browser API under constant improvement.

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/position/ , http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/height/

If performance is very important, you can gain a factor by diving into their implementation and improving it for your specific case, but keep in mind that the complexity will not go below O(number of DOM elements)